# Increase character limit for Opencart information page

Tags: opencart

I have a store that was built with Opencart 2. I create a page for information. This information is too long and Opencart and just shows part of the text. I want all of the texts and characters to show correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for the information page html is stored in a mysql `text` field which has a 64k storage limit.  If you need more than that you can change the field type to `mediumtext` which has a 16MB limit.  You can do this with a sql query like:

```
ALTER TABLE oc_information_description MODIFY description MEDIUMTEXT;
```